# SAS DI Studio create index on Oracle table

Tags: oracle, indexing, sas, data-integration

Is it possible to create an index on a column of an Oracle table registered in metadata of SAS Data Integration Studio? If it is, which type of index is created? Simple one or which one?

Answer (score 2):

yes we can create an index on output table of oracle database.After registering the output table you can find the index tab/keys tab .there we can create index(either it may be simple(for simple the index name and column name should be same) and for composite index you can able to choose multiple columns

Comment: Thanks, you are right. My question had another context. I meant to "create" an index in DIS (metadata) for an existing input table that already has an index. I think this is not possible, but SAS takes automatically the index defined in Oracle.